# How to click an input role as radio located under in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am doing some automation script for the website https://silkdb.bioinfotoolkits.net in selenium using python language[image] where I have you can see a button named "Blast" that pops up a window with some default values on click.

```
<div data-meta="Field" id="program" role="radiogroup" class="next-radio-group next-radio-button next-radio-button-medium">
<label dir="ltr" aria-checked="true" class="next-radio-wrapper checked "><span class="next-radio-single-input">
   <input role="radio" tabindex="0" type="radio" aria-checked="true" class="next-radio-input"></span><span class="next-radio-label">blastn</span>
</label>

<label dir="ltr" aria-checked="false" class="next-radio-wrapper "><span class="next-radio-single-input">
<input role="radio" tabindex="-1" type="radio" aria-checked="false" class="next-radio-input"></span><span class="next-radio-label">blastx</span></label>

<label dir="ltr" aria-checked="false" class="next-radio-wrapper "><span class="next-radio-single-input"><input role="radio" tabindex="-1" type="radio" aria-checked="false" class="next-radio-input"></span><span class="next-radio-label">tblastn</span></label>

<label dir="ltr" aria-checked="false" class="next-radio-wrapper "><span class="next-radio-single-input"><input role="radio" tabindex="-1" type="radio" aria-checked="false" class="next-radio-input"></span><span class="next-radio-label">blastp</span></label></div>
```

The default label named "blastn" is selected on defualt. But I want to select lable named "blastp".

I have tried many things using xpath but I am unable to get it selected.

Please help me in this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://silkdb.bioinfotoolkits.net/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#btn-blast"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#program label:last-child span:nth-child(2)"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://silkdb.bioinfotoolkits.net/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='btn-blast']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='next-radio-label' and text()='blastp']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: blastp]

Answer (score 0):

It is important to send the click events to the appropriate receiving elements which can actually react to the click event. In this case, i think the click must be send to the input element, not the span.
Please try with the following xpath.

```
//span[@class="next-radio-label" and contains(text(),'blastp')]/preceding-sibling::span/input
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use following xpath to click your option **//span[contains(text(),'blastp')]**